# Не отправляются пакеты на другой компьютер по локальной сети

Tags: java, сокеты

Сделать программу для обмена пакетами с клиентом и сервером с помощью `DatagramSocket`. На моём компьютере всё работает, а если запускаю клиент с другого компьютера и сервер на моём компьютере, то не работает. С сетью проблем нету(веб-сервер работает между компьютерами). Брандмауэр был отключён полностью.

Код клиента:

```
public class Client {

public static DatagramSocket socket;

public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket();

        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

        byte[] data = ("Hello, World!").getBytes();

        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ip, 3000);

        socket.send(dp);

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Код сервера:

```
public class Server {

public static DatagramSocket socket;

public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(3000);
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024], 1024);
        socket.receive(dp);

        System.out.println(new String(dp.getData()));

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: На клиентской стороне прописано что Ваш компьютер является сервером?

Comment: @SergeyVlasov Да

Comment: На код можно посмотреть?

Comment: @SergeyVlasov добавил код

Comment: А ошибка какая?

Comment: Ошибку в коде не выдаёт

Comment: localhost - это имя локального компьютера. Клиент пытается подключиться к тому компьютеру, на котором запущен. Если он запущен на одном компьютере с сервером, это получается. Если на разных, то это, очевидно, получиться не может.

Comment: Я знаю, когда я запускал программу на другом компьютере я вписывал адрес 192.168.0.100(адрес сервера в моей локальной сети).

Comment: socket.connect(ip, port) попробуй у клиента

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прописать в классе **Client**

```
socket.connect(ip, port);
```